# Outlook form region right to left from C++ code

Tags: c++, outlook-addin, outlook-2010, right-to-left, outlook-2007-addin

How can I set a string to have Right-to-Left (U+200F RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK (RLM)) unicode char when editing the code itself?

Meaning, I have the given code:

```
CComPtr<MSForms::IControl> spISubjectControl;
spControls->_GetItemByName(_bstr_t(L"Subject"), &spISubjectControl);
if (spISubjectControl != NULL) {
    CComPtr<Outlook::_OlkTextBox> spSubject;
    hr = spISubjectControl.QueryInterface(&spSubject);
    if (spSubject != NULL) {
        CString subject = L"Some words in some RTL language";
        spSubject->put_Text(_bstr_t(subject));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it is not enough to add the direction and the special character in the "advance  properties" of the subject TextBox, it seems that once I change the content of the TextBox the direction is reset to LTR.

Please help :)

Thanks,

Nili

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `subject` string does contain the Unicode RLM character. Try with `L"\u200F ‏Some words in some RTL language"`. If the `\u200F` escape sequence does not work, try `\x200F` instead.